# Eclipse AVD emulator stops at black screen with time

Tags: linux, android-emulator

I've downloaded the latest Eclipse ADT bundle for linux and now I'm trying to run the "Hello world" project. 
Whenever I run the application the emulator shows android splash screen and then stops at black screen showing time and a notice in the right top corner saying "Voice actions disabled in this preview. Swipe to dismiss". I've discovered that I can do following things:

1. Turn off the phone
2. Switch into airplane mode
3. Change the volume

I'm enclosing a screenshot of the situation. 
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How did you create the AVD (the system image the emulator runs)?

Comment: You mean the settings? If yes here they are: [Settings](http://i.imgur.com/O5dIWo3.png)

Comment: Try changing the CPU to x86. It is quite likely because you have it set to Android Wear ARM.

Comment: @ChromoZoneX ARM is the only option I have.

Comment: That's odd. I'll check that when I get home. Have you tried using another device ... like the nexus 4/5 avd?

Comment: @ChromoZoneX Changing the CPU to x86 made it work! I did some updates (downloaded everything I could in Android SDK Manager) and then x86 CPU became available. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPU had to be changed to x86. Then it worked.

See question comment thread for further details.